# Auto updating when scrolling to bottom in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently developing an ASP.net C# project. I want to be able to display a set limit of data from a database, not using the grid view, I want to process the layout myself with code, onto a page. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the window, it loads up some more of the records, like the Twitter feed page does it.

I have no idea what this is called to be able to search for it.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about lazy loading and or [infinite scrolling](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/). There are many way to implement lazy loading. A simple implementation would lazy load images only, which could be done with a jQuery plugin. Beyond that, you can implement lazy loading and infinite scrolling using AJAX calls which load data on demand, similar to how traditional pagination works.

If you search around you should be able to find examples. Implementing the service to provide data to the AJAX calls should be simple with ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebForms as well though I've not actually done it with WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use some javascript/jQuery to find the scroll position, then load in more data using ajax.

jquery scrollTop can be used to determine the scroll position. Then look into jquery.ajax for loading in content.

the idea of loading more content is very similar to pagination. So the first chunk of data you can treat as page 1, then when you scroll to the bottom of the page load in page 2 and so on.